# Nx build folder structure and react import after publish

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nomachine-nx

I am trying to build a library of React components and publish it to npm to use across multiple applications using Nx and am having difficulties with/understanding the build process. My assumption is defining the `rootDir` and `exports` would accomplish this but I can't seem to get it to work.

The build looks like:

[image: Build]

When I import it as `import { Test } from '@<scope>/components'`, I get an error that the type declarations can't be found.

Ideally I would like all components accessible through the root and folder level. ie:

- `import { Test } from '@<scope>/components/core'`
- `import { Test } from '@<scope>/components'`

**Current library folder structure**

```
 - packages
   - components
     - src
       - core
         - Test
           - Test.tsx
         - index.ts
       - index.ts
     - package.json
     - project.json
     - tsconfig.json
 ...
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@<scope>/components",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "default": "./index.js"
    },
    "./core": {
      "types": "./src/core/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./src/core/index.js"
    }
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  }
}
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "name": "components",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "packages/components/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    ...
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/rollup:rollup",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/packages/components",
        "tsConfig": "packages/components/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "packages/components/package.json",
        "entryFile": "packages/components/src/index.ts",
        "external": ["react/jsx-runtime", "typescript"],
        "rollupConfig": "@nrwl/react/plugins/bundle-rollup",
        "rootDir": "packages/components/src",
        "compiler": "babel",
        "deleteOutputPath": true,
        "format": ["esm"],
        "updateBuildableProjectDepsInPackageJson": true,
        "buildableProjectDepsInPackageJsonType": "dependencies",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "packages/components/README.md",
            "input": ".",
            "output": "."
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json"
}
```